# What would cause the polymeric sand in my patio to soften after curing?

Tags: hard-landscape, patio

We recently got a flagstone patio with polymeric sand in the joints. The polymeric sand was put down on a Friday early afternoon, and when I checked on it Sunday morning it had hardened and felt like concrete. But after a rain on Monday it was completely soft again—the consistency was like wet sand on the beach. Our contractor (who has really good reviews and a lot of experience) says he's never seen this before, and all the research I've done has warned about rain within 6-24 hours after laying down the polymeric sand, but this was multiple days and it had already hardened.

What could have caused this?

Comment: Could the contents have gotten damp in the bag due to poor handling or storage?

Comment: @kevinskio the contractor left the bag with us and it seems very dry, so I don't think so.